# Lector de huella digital

Tags: c#, biometrico

tengo un lector de huella UareU 4500 fingerPrint, y necesito hacer una aplicacion de control de asistencia por huella.

Baje el FreeFingerprintVerificationSDK 1.0 que funciona bien pero solo permite enrolar a 10 personas como maximo y yo necesito muchas mas, hay alguna otra alternativa a esto, algun otro sdk u otra cosa?

gracias

Answer (score 1):

hay un buen tutorial acerca del uso de este lector en particular y que me fue muy util, son varios videos en donde utilizan Vb.net pero te explica paso a paso como implementar la dll que viene en el sdk. te dejo el link del video:
[Lector de huellas UareU DigitalPersona](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h80tCq2MTGI)

Espero te sea util.

Comment: gracias, voy a dar un vistado